# C++: Using wrapper classes with stack implementation?

Tags: c++, stack, wrapper

My C++ instructor recently gave us an assignment that basically told us to translate a bunch of linked list functions into linked stack functions using wrapper classes as much as possible. Unfortunately, however, he didn't explain them very clearly so I'm not entirely sure how they're used nor how they're implemented.

As of right now, my "Stack_Wrapper" class kind of just looks like this:

```
template<class S>
struct Node
{
    S data;
    Node<S>* next;
};

template<class S>
class Stack_Wrapper
{
public:
    Stack_Wrapper();
    Stack_Wrapper(const Stack_Wrapper<S>& altStack);
    ~Stack_Wrapper();

    const Stack_Wrapper<S>& operator = (const Stack_Wrapper<S>&);
    void Initialize();
    bool IsEmpty();
    bool IsFull();
    void Push(const S& newItem);
    void Pop(S& poppedElement);
    void Destroy();

protected:
    Stack_Wrapper<S> *first;
    Stack_Wrapper<S> *last;
};
```

I suppose what I am asking is: how would I start translating this to use wrappers?

Comment: In essence just make a member variable that has your inner container, then your wrapper class calls methods on the inner container. This is how std::stack works for the most part.

Comment: A lot depends on what your linked list provides, but a look through the `[stack]` section of the C++ standard (section 23.6.5 as of the N3797 draft) might give at least some ideas.